# how to write response in switch case using nodejs

Tags: node.js, postman

In console it shows response but in postman shows sending request like that only. How can I return a valid response in postman. How can I write code for this one i tried all.

This is my code so far:

```
 var sendStreamingTemplate = function (req, res) {

    authToken = req.headers.authorization;
    userAuthObj = JSON.parse(UserAuthServices.userAuthTokenValidator(authToken));
    var todayDate = new Date();
    var expireDate = new Date(userAuthObj.expire_date);
    tokenOK = TokenValidator.validateToken(userAuthObj.user_id, authToken).then(function (userSessions) {
        if (userSessions.length === 1) {
            if (expireDate >= todayDate) {
                StreamingTemplateId = req.params.id;

                Template.findById(StreamingTemplateId).then(function (streamingTemplate) {
                    if (streamingTemplate === null) {
                        res.status(404).json({
                            message: 'Streaming not found...'
                        })
                    } else {

                        console.log(streamingTemplate);
                      switch(streamingTemplate.template_name.toString().toLowerCase()){
                               case "notification":
                              //if write return response means it will return something went wrong
                                break;
                               case "invoice":

                                break;
                               case "voucher":

                                break;
                               default:

                               break;
                           }
                    }
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    res.status(500).json({
                        message: 'something went wrong...'
                    });
                });
            } else {
                res.status(401).json({
                    message: 'Not Authorized...'
                });
            }
        } else {
            res.status(401).json({
                message: 'Token Expired...'
            });
        }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Token Expired...'
        });
    });
};
```

This is the the output in the console:

```
Instance { 
    dataValues: { 
        id: 1, template_name: 'StreamNotification', description: 'Streaming', template_content: 'Mail notification', is_active: true 
    }, 
    _previousDataValues: {     
        id: 1, template_name: 'StreamNotification', description: 'Streaming', template_content: 'Mail notification', is_active: true 
    }, 
    _changed: {
    },
}
```

Comment: someone help me please

Comment: **"in console it shows response but in postman shows sending request like that only.how i will return response in postman"** this is not helping to understand your problem. Explain your problem properly so others can aid. Also try adding some others tag like `postman` in your question.

Comment: this  is my console output.

Comment: i want this output in postman also.

Comment: what its showing the response in `postman` now??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you hit the switch statement the code isn't setting the response. Try adding this immediately after your `console.log` line:

```
res.json(streamingTemplate)
```

or even

```
res.send(streamingTemplate)
```

depending on the type of `streamingTemplate`. You might need to vary the response depending on the switch statement, in which case you could set some return value in each `case` then move the response to the end of the switch. Depends what you are trying to do.

Comment: i want to send the response in table format through mail like html table.tableheaders and corresponding data then out of the table write the message.

Comment: case "notification":
                               result: '<html><head><style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;}th, td {padding: 10px;text-align: left;}</style></head>' +
                                '<body><table style="width:100%"><tr><th>Broadcaster</th><th>Broadcasterchannel</th><th>status</th></tr>' +' <p>Message:Streaming sucessfully running...</p>'+
                                '}</table></body></html>'
                                break;

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is here but sending an email is unrelated to sending a http response. Try adding a call to your mail module before sending the HTTP response.

Comment: is it that's my question?.whatever i am getting from this res.json(streamingTemplate) i have to send this data through mail and that  format is table format.

Comment: Have you got a mail solution already? If not, have a look at https://nodemailer.com/about/. Or is the problem that your mail service isn't accepting what you're sending it?

Comment: sending mail is not a problem for me.but above response i want to send mail.is there any way getting response and send mail instead of this method

Comment: If you can send mail without a problem, do that immediately after `console.log(streamingTemplate)`